# Please explain this regex to me

Tags: php, regex, explode, preg-split

I came across the following to split a string into "tokens":

```
$tokens = preg_split("/[^\-_A-Za-z0-9]+/", $string);
```

Could somebody explain to me how this is different from this:

```
$tokens = explode(' ', $string);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The regular expression you provided:

```
$tokens = preg_split("/[^\-_A-Za-z0-9]+/", $string);
```

will split an input string into tokens using a delimiter that is not a dash (-), underscore (_), letter (lowercase or uppercase), or number.

Whereas:

```
$tokens = explode(' ', $string);
```

Will only split the string into tokens using whitespace as a delimiter.

Answer (score 2):

The literal reading of `[^\-_A-Za-z0-9]+` is:

> Match one or more induvidual characters that is not `-` or `_` or a letter A to Z (capitalized or not) or a digit.

`preg_split` will split the input based on matches to the above, but `explode` will only split on a whitespace literal. There are other characters not excluded from the regular expression which `preg_split` will split on but `explode` won't, so the resulting arrays could be different.

Comment: \ is not one of the characters that will be used in the match. It is there in order to escape the - character.